# Do common compilers know that these code-versions do the same and use this fact to optimize?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code snippets:

```
class MyClass1{
public:
  double value;
  MyClass1 &operator*=(const MyClass1 &right){
    value *= right.value;
    return *this;
  }
  friend MyClass1 operator*(const MyClass1 &left, const MyClass1 &right){
    auto result = left;
    result *= right;
    return result;
  }
};
```

and

```
class MyClass2{
public:
  double value;
  MyClass2(double v) : value(v){}
  MyClass2(){}
  friend MyClass2 operator*(const MyClass2 &left, const MyClass2 &right){
    return MyClass2 (left.value * right.value);
  }
};
```

What I am interested in is: Do common compilers know, that the operators MyClass1::operator* and MyClass2::operator* give the same result. Further more do they make the same executable out of them, if the settings say, that someone want"s to have an highly optimized executable? In principle they do the same.

I read the "unoptimized" assembly code of that (made by Visual C++) and they look different. But the performance optimized assembly code is very huge, complex and (for me) hard to understand.

In the non-optimized version, the second implementation is nearly three times faster than the first one.

Comment: *Make compiler optimazations that the bytecode ...* what!?

Comment: First of all, Most C++ compilers doesn't generate bytecode, they generate executable code. However, most compiler also allow you to generate *assembler* code, and you can use that options to compare the generated code at different optimization levels to see what it does.

Comment: Most compilers won't generate assembly code from garbage though

Comment: Yes, I meant executable code instead of byte code.

Comment: Also, still need to fix occurrences of "MyClass" to the numbered versions.

Comment: @Matthias why are you even pasting "code out of your head" and make people guess what you mean, when there's plenty of online compilers like ideone available?

Comment: @PeterT Sorry, I am an old offline programmer and I have never heard about online compilers in C/C++. And I hoped that the mistakes do not affect the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You have bigger issues in your code, but here's a nice online service to use to examine the generated assembly:

- **[http://gcc.godbolt.org/](http://goo.gl/ISEVXX)**

[image]

I'd say it's a good idea not to bother about optimizing until you know how to make your code correct. That said, if a nice online tool can help you put your worries to rest, all the better!

### Demo Source Code

The screenshot liked aboe was adapted from your question. DISCLAIMER: it's solid undefined behaviour (due to unitialized values at least):

```
struct MyClass1{
  double value;
  MyClass1 &operator*=(MyClass1 const &right){
    value *= right.value;
    return *this;
  }
  friend MyClass1 operator*(MyClass1 const &left, MyClass1 const &right){
    auto result = left;
    result *= right;
    return result;
  }
};

class MyClass2{
public:
  double value;
  MyClass2(double v = 0.0) : value(v){}
  friend MyClass2 operator*(MyClass2 const &left, MyClass2 const &right){
    return left.value * right.value;
  }
};

template <typename T> double test() {
    T a,b;
    volatile T c = a * b;
    return c.value;
}

int main()
{
    return test<MyClass1>() + test<MyClass2>();
}
```

Corresponding assembly for this demo on my VM with clang 3.4 -O3 -march=corei7-avx is:

```
    .file   "test.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    vmulsd  %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0
    vmovsd  %xmm0, -8(%rsp)
    vmovsd  -8(%rsp), %xmm0
    movq    $0, -8(%rsp)
    vaddsd  -8(%rsp), %xmm0, %xmm0
    vcvttsd2si  %xmm0, %eax
    ret
.Ltmp0:
    .size   main, .Ltmp0-main
    .cfi_endproc


    .ident  "Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using struct MyClass1 instead of class MyClass1?

Comment: Yes. To reduce on typing. No need to make everything public explicitly :) (also, that has _nothing_ to do with the answer or the question)